# Change default session to Lubuntu from LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I installed Lubuntu on top of Ubuntu 16.04.3 server, using

```
apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

Now, from the login screen Lubuntu interface works fine. However, if I try to login via vnc, using `servername:1`, LXDE session starts up by default. LXDE session is a bit different, launches with a different theme and icons.
This session is available from the login screen but is not default at the login screen. how can i make sure vnc logs into Lubuntu session and not LXDE?

Comment: What happens if you connect via VNC to a pure Lubuntu system (that is installed from a Lubuntu iso file)? I would think that it is more likely to default to the Lubuntu desktop, but I don't know, I am not using VNC.

Comment: I haven't tested that. I will test it.

Comment: LXDE is the default for lubuntu,..

Comment: @ravery, Thanks. yes, i got that but I want Lubuntu session to be default not LXDE.

Comment: default is LXDE